# Passing AES Encrypted Value As Parameter To .NET Web Api Service

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebService developed with .NET Web Api. For a GET request, the service need to receive a parameter which is a AES Encrypted value. My route is mapped as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "GetValueApi",
  routeTemplate: "api/ctrl/{key}",
  defaults: new { controller = "MyController" }
);
```

However, when I try to call the URL with a value such an encrypted and URL encoded parameter such as `2VUI8n3CMhsHtV0YF9a3CIIMeiuh5j%2bjd2bGCq3k2GjJBEY1%2bkIQ1eOwGcgLUu0USWK%2fkQ%3d%3d`, it seems as though the HttpHandler is URL decoding the parameter before the route is mapped, and the route cannot be resolved.

For example:

`http://example.com/api/ctrl/2VUI8n3CMhsHtV0YF9a3CIIMeiuh5j%2bjd2bGCq3k2GjJBEY1%2bkIQ1eOwGcgLUu0USWK%2fkQ%3d%3d`

Results in:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

From the Errror Details of IIS, I have:

Requested URL
`http://example.com/api/ctrl/2VUI8n3CMhsHtV0YF9a3CIIMeiuh5j+jd2bGCq3k2GjJBEY1+kIQ1eOwGcgLUu0USWK/kQ==`

So clearly the URL parameter was decoded before the route was mapped.

If on the other hand, I just call the URL with a dummy parameter such as:
`http://example.com/api/ctrl/x`

The route resolves.

Can someone help me to see what I am missing here? Aside from URL encoding what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137032/web-api-accept-encoded-forward-slashes-in-any-url-segment , which doesn't seem to have a solution yet.